# Correct usage: 'frictions in the market' or 'frictions on the market'

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I am searching for the correct usage of this term: Should I say 'frictions in the market' or 'frictions on the market'?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, I'm afraid. I don't know the context of this sentence, so have little idea what you are trying to say. Please give more information.

Comment: I'd expect frictions **within** the market. "*On the market*" would imply between the market and something else. "*In the market*" works, but de-emphasizes the internal structures of the market that are responsible for friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Market Friction or Frictions in the market. Generally, the former is used in the Press media.